# How to create a list with data tables as items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

What I want is to create a list where each item in that list is an data table like below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZels.jpg Example data table The user needs to be able to sort items in the data table and needs to be able to sort the data tables itself.

Each table is going to represent a client and each item in that table is an order. The user will then collect the orders, if he collected an order the order wil dissapear but the user is also able to bring them back.

I've tried to put a Recyclerview inside a Recyclerview but this caused unitended side effects and bugs, also I read online that it is basically a bad practice. My initial intention was to use a recylcerview with a sortedlist.

I did some searching online and a lot of people recommended using categories between items so that you only need one list. But because I have data tables (CardViews) that can be independent sorted this isn't an option.

If anyone want to give me a nudge in the right direction, I would be really thankful.

Comment: what did you tried so far show your efforts first

Comment: What I tried I tried to put a Recyclerview inside a Recyclerview but this caused unitended side effects and bugs, also I read online that it is basically a bad practice. My initial intention was to use a recylcerview with a sortedlist. - comes out of the question....

Comment: Can you please post code or things that you have done?